# Email sending using smtp in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am not familiar with sending mail using smtp , i tried with this code but i didnt get any email . I want to know should i set any configuration in my webmail.

```
$email_config = Array(
                    'protocol'  => 'smtp',
                    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
                    'smtp_port' => '465',
                    'smtp_user' =>  'noreply@mydomain.com',
                    'smtp_pass' =>  '1234563767',
                    'mailtype'  => 'html',
                    'starttls'  => true,
                    'newline'   => "\r\n"
                    );      
    $this->load->library('email', $email_config);
    $this->email->from('noreply@mydomain.com', 'enquiry');
    $this->email->to("test@mydomain.com");
    $this->email->subject('Package Enquiry');
    $email = $this->load->view('packages/enquiry',true);
    $this->email->message($email);
    $this->email->send();
```